# Error de Set-Cookie con vue y laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, axios

Estoy intentando hacer un login desde vue conectándose a laravel utilizando axios pero cuando hago la peticion me sale el siguiente error.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo en Vue es el siguiente.

```js
 import axios from 'axios' 
  axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;


  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        erroo:'',
        resul :'',
        model: {
          email: '',
          password: '',
          rememberMe: false
        }
      };
    },
    methods: {
   
      onSubmit() {
       
          
          axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then(() => {
              
          });
         
        }
      }
  };
```

No se si a alguien mas le ha salido este error y sabe como solucionarlo.
Gracias.

Comment: Por favor, pon el mensaje de error _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error estaba en que el dominio Front era localhost y el de laravel era 127.0.0.1, simplemente hice que el servidor de laravel iniciara tambien localhost con el siguiente comando
`php artisan serve --host localhost`   
Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

**Laravel** almacena un `token CSRF` en una cookie que se incluye con cada respuesta y solicitud generada.

Esta cookie se envía principalmente al usar **ANGULAR, jQuery, AXIOS** y otros **Frameworks** y librerías de **JavaScript**.

Revisa esta documentación en donde se ve ese tema:
[Protección CSRF](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/csrf#csrf-x-xsrf-token)

Además de comprobar el token, el middleware comprobara el encabezado de la solicitud.
Por ejm podrías almacenar el token en una etiqueta:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Luego agregar automáticamente el token a todos los encabezados de solicitud:

```
axios.get('https://...', {
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
          //...
   })
```

> Me comunicas si te pude resolver tu problema o por lo menos ayudar un poco.

Comment: Ya logre solucionarlo, el error era que el dominio Front ere localhost y el de laravel era 127.0.0.1, simplemente hice que el servidor de laravel iniciara tambien localhost y ya. muchas gracias por tu ayuda